# spark.executorEnv doesn't seem to take any effect

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, pyspark

According to the Spark [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), there is a way to pass environment variables to spawned executors:

> spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName] Add the environment variable specified by EnvironmentVariableName to the Executor process. The user can specify multiple of these to set multiple environment variables.

I'm trying to direct my pyspark app to use a specific python executable(anaconda environment with numpy etc etc), which is usually done by altering the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable in `spark-env.sh`. Although this way works, shipping new config to all the cluster nodes  every time I want to switch a virtualenv looks like a huge overkill.

That's why I tried to pass PYSPARK_PYTHON in the following way:

```sh
uu@e1:~$ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark --conf \
spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/share/anaconda/bin/python" \
--master spark://e1.local:7077
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

```python
In [1]: sc._conf.getAll()
Out[1]: 
[(u'spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON', u'/usr/share/anaconda/bin/python'),
 (u'spark.rdd.compress', u'True'),
 (u'spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', u'100'),
 (u'spark.master', u'spark://e1.local:7077'),
 (u'spark.submit.deployMode', u'client'),
 (u'spark.app.name', u'PySparkShell')]

In [2]: def dummy(x):
    import sys
    return sys.executable
   ...: 

In [3]: sc.parallelize(xrange(100),50).map(dummy).take(10)

Out[3]: 
['/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7',
 '/usr/bin/python2.7']
```

My `spark-env.sh` does not have `PYSPARK_PYTHON` configured, so this is just the default python that gets called. Some additional info: it's spark 1.6.0 standalone mode cluster.

Am I missing something important here?

Comment: if correctly understood, you want your driver to use 
/usr/bin/python2.7 and executors to use /usr/share/anaconda/bin/python?

Comment: Oh, ipython, I'm using to launch driver is actually /usr/share/anaconda/bin/python too. I guess, I wan't it to be consistent across the cluster, but I'd prefer switching between pythons occasionally.

Comment: Not sure if this will help.
taking a quick peek at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark
I think they are just doing export 
Can you do
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/share/anaconda/bin/python"
to see if it applies that to all executors
and then just run
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark

Comment: It is a great catch sir! I think, you should put it as an answer and get an upvote & accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a quick peek at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark

I think they are just doing export 
Can you do

export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/share/anaconda/bin/python"

to see if it applies that to all executors
and then just run

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark